# installing glassfish 3.1.2 in command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glassfish

I am trying to install glassfish on Ubuntu server 11.10, but the installer found on the official page requier display to be set. I dont have anything other than a command line interface. How do i get this working? I have installed everything pre-required (sun-java6-jre, jar handler)

Answer (score 3):

You could download the zip version, unpack and configure it manually.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try that one. Found a tutorial on google that explains howto.

Comment: This worked for me getting glassfish working on a debian system.

Comment: This tutorial ? http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-301-on-ubuntu

Comment: its exactly the same tutorial i found, have some issues in it i have not managed to do, but gonna start from the top again in case i missed some points.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo apt-get install glassfish-*`

Comment: i got it installed that way, but not running as a service. Going to check more into that. Thanks for the help

Comment: I did this but don't know where to go next. Where is it installed? Where are the configuration files?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, regarding your sun-java6-jre package, GlassFish requires the JDK, not the JRE.

Comment: Hey vince. Yes, generically speaking, but we also don't test with the JRE.